# Why can I not install modules on Python

Tags: python, module, installation

I'm coding this on IDLE on a MacBook, if that's helpful to anyone.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
pip install pynput

from pynput import keyboard

def get_key_name(key):
    if isinstance(key, keyboard.KeyCode):
        return key.char
    else:
        return str(key)

def on_press(key):
    key_name = get_key_name(key)
    print('Key {} pressed.'.format(key_name))

def on_release(key):
    key_name = get_key_name(key)
    print('Key {} released.'.format(key_name))

    if key_name == 'Key.esc':
        print('Exiting...')
        return False

with keyboard.Listener(
    on_press = on_press,
    on_release = on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I am trying to install pynput. But it keeps saying invalid syntax around "install". Can someone help me out please? Thanks!

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Have you installed the module?

Comment: @AMC it literally just says invalid syntax. I'm kind of new to modules, so I was confused on how to install it:
https://pypi.org/project/pynput/ this is what I was trying to download

Comment: In that case, I think you need a guide/tutorial on installing and managing dependencies, **which is outside the scope of Stack Overflow**. Personally, I'm also on macOS and can vouch for Conda, I think it's quite beginner friendly.

Comment: do you have a website or anything that I could use?

Comment: _do you have a website or anything that I could use?_ Conda has its own documentation, although a simple Google search for "python managing dependencies", "python installing packages", etc. should yield some good results.

Comment: You cannot use `pip install` as part of Python code because that is not valid Python code. You need to install your modules (pynput) *outside* of IDLE, then start IDLE again to run your code.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `pip install pynput` from command prompt. You cannot use pip install in your py code file.

If you want to install it from code. Try the following:-

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
install('pynput')
```

Comment: Remove pip install pynput from code and try to do it from command prompt

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to encourage people to run pip like that, or to not use virtual environments.

Comment: @Vaibhav it's saying that in the command prompt that it's "invalid syntax"

Comment: @ZarekKhaishgi actually the above code should work. Try ti just type python in command prompt and hit enter and check what you get

Comment: @Vaibhav it's giving me a bunch of errors in the module now

Comment: @ZarekKhaishgi Don't run the code. Only run the ```python``` in command prompt

Comment: @Vaibhav oh I was, I'll run it in the shell

Comment: @Vaibhav It's giving me this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zarekkhaishgi/Documents/keystroke.py", line 5, in <module>
    install('pynput')
  File "/Users/zarekkhaishgi/Documents/keystroke.py", line 4, in install
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: I will tell you run only that. Open your shell and run only ```pip install pynput```

Comment: And once you run this, pynput will get install and then you run your python code without ```pip install pynput```